# BroadcastReceiver прекращает выполнятсья после нескольких выполнений

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, android-dialog, android-alarm-manager

Написал вот такой код. отправляется запрос на сервер, ответ парситься и в зависимости от ответа создается или не создается диалоговое окно с некоторым наполнением которое пришло в ответе. запрос отправляется регулярно но когда появляется окно запрос отправляется только 2 раза а потом BroadcastReceiver не выполняется значит следующий запрос не отправляется и окно уже не прячется. Дело в том что хотелось бы менять содержимое диалогового окна когда информация на сервере поменялась ну или когда информация уже не актуальна чтоб оно пряталось.

```
 private void SelectMethod(Node dataNode) {
    switch (dataNode.getNodeName()) {
        case "track_get_alarm":
            List<Track> alar = xmlP.GetNumTracksFromNode(Track.STATUS.alarm, dataNode);
            if (alar.size() != 0){
                DialogShow(getString(R.string.alarm), alar);
                break;
            }
            break;
}
private void DialogShow(String name, final List<Track> trk) {
    final CharSequence[] chr = new CharSequence[trk.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < chr.length; i++) {
        Track t = trk.get(i);
        chr[i] = getString(R.string.track) + t.id + getString(R.string.atzone) + t.zone;
    }
    Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    this.startActivity(main);
    isStopped = true;
    Vibrate(true);
    PlaySound(true);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle(name);
    builder.setItems(chr, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Vibrate(false);
            PlaySound(false);
            msgChecking = "запрос";
            new XmlSending().execute(msgChecking);

        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    alarm = builder.create();
    alarm.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alarm.setCancelable(false);
    alarm.show();
}
private class XmlSending extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String resp = "";
        if (!isDialog) {
            XMLSender sender = new XMLSender(SERVER_IP, PORT);
            try {
                resp = sender.Send(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (params[0].equals(msgGetWarningAlarm)){
            prevResponse = newResponse;
            newResponse = resp;
        }
        return resp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Node nl = xmlP.GetReply(s);
        if (!xmlP.CheckError(nl)) {
            SelectMethod(nl);
        }
        else {
            workError(nl);
        }
    }
}

private void RegisterAlarmBroadcast() {
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        // private static final String TAG = "Alarm Example Receiver";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if  (isStopped){
                UnregisterAlarmBroadcast();
            }
            if (alarm != null && !prevResponse.equals(newResponse)) {
                if (alarm.isShowing()) {
                    DialogStop();
                }
            }
            allertContext = context;
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("sample"), 0);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
            setAlarm(delay, pendingIntent);
            new XmlSending().execute(msgGetWarningAlarm);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("sample"));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("sample"), 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    setAlarm(delay, pendingIntent);
}

private void setAlarm(int delayInMillis, PendingIntent sender){
    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    long timeInMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() + delayInMillis) / 1000 * 1000;     //> example
    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
    else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);
    }
}

private void UnregisterAlarmBroadcast() {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```